# Webpack include directory for dynamic imports

Tags: javascript, webpack, create-react-app, es6-modules, dynamic-import

I'm new to Webpack and I'm trying to dynamically import parts of a module, e.g. `import(path)` where `path` is always `codemirror/modes/XXX/YYY`.

With static imports, these work- but with dynamic they are not found.

How can I get Webpack to bundle everything in this directory?

Comment: Hey! Did you get this working?